# Vuetify V-menu wont render

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using this exact code from the documentation

```
<div class="d-flex justify-center align-center">
  <v-menu offset-y>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-btn color="primary" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"> Dropdown </v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-list>
      <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
  </v-menu>
</div>
```

to render it

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

but sadly, I'm getting it

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

the dropdown button is completely invisible

I'm using the Vuetify version 2.3.6

Comment: Any console errors? Can you link to a reproduction?

Comment: No errors on console

Comment: Do you have you application wrapped in the v-app component. Elseway Vuetify components can be used in your project. 

You can read more about this in 
[link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/#api)